# HTML5 input type does not render correctly when publishing

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, html

I have already download and install this package to support HTML5 input type

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2468871

The following is code in my page

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head runat="server">

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <input id="testEmail" type="email" />
        </div>
        <div>

        </div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="testEmailAsp" runat="server" type="email"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="testUrlAsp" runat="server" type="url"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="textBoxTest" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This code is generated when running in visual studion 2010

```
<input name="testEmailAsp" type="text" id="testEmailAsp" type="email" />
<input name="testUrlAsp" type="text" id="testUrlAsp" type="url" />
<input name="textBoxTest" type="text" id="textBoxTest" />
<input type="submit" name="Button1" value="Button" id="Button1" />
```

When publish to the server. it renders like this.

```
<input name="testEmailAsp" type="text" id="testEmailAsp" type="email" />
<input name="testUrlAsp" type="text" id="testUrlAsp" type="url" />
<input name="textBoxTest" type="text" id="textBoxTest" />
<input type="submit" name="Button1" value="Button" id="Button1" />
```

As you can see. it render type 2 time so the markup is incorrect and that make the [input type keyboard](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/768.cfm) on mobile not work.

Comment: I guess! you need to set <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to install that on the server as well, i don't know that

Answer (score 0):

This may sound silly but does IE9 support HTML5 input type="email", url

http://html5test.com/

Comment: This site shows that IE9 does NOT support `input type="email"` when I visit it in IE9.